# Given a DDS topic name, can the topic type information be determined at run-time?

Tags: c++, publish-subscribe, rtti, data-distribution-service

I am evaluating RTI ConnextDDS, working in C++.  At run-time, on reading a DDS message and extracting the topic name, is there an API that offers run-time type information concerning that topic?  That is can I get the name and type of each element in the topic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, although not straightforward.

Doing this in a completely dynamic way requires inspection of the so-called built-in Topics, which contain information about the different DDS Entities discovered. See [Chapter 17 "Built-In Topics" in the Core Libraries User's Manual](https://community.rti.com/static/documentation/connext-dds/5.3.0/doc/manuals/connext_dds/html_files/RTI_ConnextDDS_CoreLibraries_UsersManual/index.htm#UsersManual/builtintopics.htm#builtintopics_3745276171_40053%3FTocPath%3DPart%25203%253A%2520Advanced%2520Concepts%7CBuilt-In%2520Topics%7C_____0). [This RTI community example on built-in Topics](https://community.rti.com/examples/builtin-topics) might help as well.

In particular, the `PublicationBuiltinTopic` and the `SubscriptionBuiltinTopic` contain the fields `type` and `type_code`, which are both intended to contain a description of the type associated with the `Topic` for the DataWriter or DataReader in question. The `type` field is of a `TypeObject` which is standardized in the [OMG DDS-XTypes specification](http://www.omg.org/spec/DDS-XTypes/). The `type_code` field is a proprietary format, as explained in the User's Manual.

Before going down this entire path, I would make sure that this is something you actually want to do, and why? Ideally, the tooling that comes with the product should provide you with all the information you need.